# I'm confused on the limit of $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, exponential-function

Okay so I read Richard Rusczyk's AoPS Volume 2 Book, and I stumbled upon the part where he informs very briefly that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$. But he doesn't really provide a rigorous proof as to why that's true (not criticizing him or anything).. It would really help if someone could provide me with the **simplest** proof possible as to why $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Often this is taken as the _definition_ of $e$. What is the definition you are using?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider the slightly more fundamental problem, does the sequence $(1 + 1/n)^n$ for $n = 1,2,3,\dots$ have a limit?  If it does have a limit, it makes sense to use that limit as the definition of $e$.

Comment: Concerning its convergence/divergence, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482253/proving-montonity-and-convergence-of-sequence-en-1-1-nn) might be useful.

Comment: I saw a computation of that limit once. It was somehow unsatisfactory, because what you can say is that the result exists and is between $2$ and $3$. You then define $e$ as the limit.

Comment: See also: [What is the most elementary proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/389793) and [How come such different methods result in the same number, $e$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/39170)

Answer (score 0):

Assume $e$ is defined by $e := \sum_\limits{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{k!}$

Let

$$y=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$
$$\ln y=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$\ln y=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$
using L'Hôpital's rule
$$\ln y = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{-1}{n^{2}}*\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}}{\frac{-1}{n^{2}}}$$
$$\ln y = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$\ln y = 1$$
$$y=e$$

Comment: You took $\ln$ to prove $y=e$? Be responsible, please, and provide an appropriate answer for the future readers. Moreover, you cannot use _L Hôspital_ at this moment (for the same reason).  

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya I'm not sure what you mean? This is how it was originally shown to me.

Comment: Just think about what you write and be aware.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya okay... is there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: This is the only answer which isn't circular:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1898375/721644

Comment: Your answer is circular. There is a slight difference in the question in the thread, but you haven't proven anything.

Comment: You're using _L Hôspital_ for $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$ You know what $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ equals only by definition. You cannot prove a definition via itself.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya The OP is not asking to prove that $e$ is defined by $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ but simply that it is equivalent. So I should be able to assume that $e$ has already been defined via a different method.

Comment: "So I should be able to assume that e has already been defined"  But none of us can *possible* answer the OPs question unless we know what the OPs definition is.  And frankly, I don't the the OP does have a definition.  I think Rucsyk was *defining* $e$ and the OP never realized that OP actually *had* a definition.

Comment: On the other hand if $Ln = \int_{1}^x \frac 1t dt$ and $exp(x) =Ln^{-1}(x)$ and $b^x = exp(xLn(x))$ and $e=exp(1)$ are our definitions then I think this is an okay explanation as to why $e = \lim (1 +\frac 1n)^n$.

Comment: @fleablood thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

Using binomial expansion

$$(1+1/n)^n=1+n(1/n)+n(n-1)/2!(1/     
n)^2+...$$

$$=1+(1/1!)+(1/2!)(1-\frac{1}{n})+...$$

As $n\rightarrow\infty$, RHS$=1+(1/1!)+(1/2!)+...=e$

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of $e?$

In many books by definition $e = \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n.$

In some books $e$ is defined as $e = \sum_\limits{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{k!}$

But we can prove these are equal.

Lets define  $e = \sum_\limits{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{k!}$

This proof can be found in baby Rudin.

Let $t_n = (1+\frac 1n)^n$

and $s_n = \sum_\limits{k=0}^{n} \frac {1}{k!}$

Expand $(1+\frac {1}{n})^n$ using the binomial theorem.

$t_n = 1 + \frac {n}{n} + \frac 12 (1 - \frac 1n) + \frac 1{3!} (1 - \frac 1n)(1-\frac 2n) + \cdots + \frac {1}{n!} (1-\frac {1}{n})\cdots(1-\frac {n-1}{n})$

Every term in $t_n$ is less than or equal to its corresponding term in $s_n$

$t_n \le s_n$

$\limsup_\limits{n\to \infty} t_n \le e$

Choose some $m < n$

Looking at the first $m$ terms of $t_n$

$1 + 1 + \frac 12 (1 - \frac 1n) + \frac 1{3!} (1 - \frac 1n)(1-\frac 2n) + \cdots + \frac {1}{m!} (1-\frac {1}{n})\cdots(1-\frac {m-1}{n})$

Let $n$ approach infinity, keeping $m$ fixed.

$1 + 1 + \frac 1{2} + \frac 1{3!} + \cdots + \frac {1}{m!} = s_m$

Since there are additional terms in $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n$ and all are positive.

$s_m \le \liminf_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n$

Letting $m$ go to infinity.

$e\le \liminf_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n$

And by the squeeze theorem, $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n = e$

Answer (score 0):

I think at that stage all you need to know is that the limit exists. We simply call it $e,$ for short.

So how can we tell that the limit exists?

The simplest way I know is already provided as an answer (albeit partial; this answer completes it) -- expand the binomial, and when you take limits as $n\to \infty,$ you get an infinite series which can be proven to exist by elementary comparisons, thus.

So we have $$1+1+1/2+1/3!+1/4!+1/5!+\cdots\le 1+1+1/2+1/2^2+1/2^3+1/2^4+\cdots=1+1/(1-1/2)=1+2=3.$$ Since the series has only positive terms, the sequence of partial sums increases monotonically, and therefore the limit must exist. We've simultaneously shown that this number $e$ is not up to $3.$ In fact, by adding up sufficiently many terms of the series, we obtain $e=2.718281828459045\ldots,$ to the first $15$ places of decimal. Stare at it -- it's easy to memorise.

Answer (score -1):

This is of the form $1^\infty$ as $ n \to \infty$.

Now for any limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x)^{g(x)}$ of the form $1^\infty$ we have direct formula to be : $e^{lim_{n\to\infty}(f(x)-1)(g(x))}$.

Now $f(x)=1+\frac{1}{n}$ and $g(x)=n$. Evaluating using the above formula the limit comes out to be : $$e^{lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n}-1)n}=e^{lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{1}{n})n}=e.$$

Comment: Your answer is also circular. Table limits come from definitions.

Comment: You make look at this:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3521928/721644

Comment: If you derive thise formula, you'll see. 

Comment: You're also missing the $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}$ in the exponent.

Comment: I have to say this answer is circular to the point of meaninglessness.

Comment: @fleablood is there any problem with the solution? I don't see any.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya thanks for the feedback.